# Is it possible to use DPDK in a server with single NIC?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, nic, linux-kernel

I have a a server with single NIC which has 4 pci ports. I already tried DPDK binding so before binding "dpdk-devbind.py -s" returns this :

```
Network devices using kernel driver
0000:01:00.0 'OneConnect NIC (Skyhawk) 0720' if=eth0 drv=be2net unused=vfio-pci *Active*
0000:01:00.1 'OneConnect NIC (Skyhawk) 0720' if=eth1 drv=be2net unused=vfio-pci
0000:01:00.2 'OneConnect NIC (Skyhawk) 0720' if=eth2 drv=be2net unused=vfio-pci
0000:01:00.3 'OneConnect NIC (Skyhawk) 0720' if=eth3 drv=be2net unused=vfio-pci
```

Though I couldn't find the NIC model in [DPDK officcially supported hardware](https://core.dpdk.org/supported/) list, the provider said it is DPDk compatible.
my "ifconfig" returns :

```
eth0: **some stuffs*** <IP>
lo: **some stuff**
```

Now, as I have only 1 IP exposed how can I use DPDK? as to bind DPDK I have to down the PCI port from ifconfig and I will lose SSH. As I can see other unused 3 pci ports, how to use them? I bound DPDK with 01:00.1 PCI port which was seen listed in DPDK compatible driver list but then what? as that was not accessible through kernel/ifconfig (no IP/interface assigned) how to even use it now from outside the server or is it even possible with single NIC? if so then how.

Answer (score 0):

DPDK is a user-space process which allows to access the NIC ports in userspace with UIO driver and not a kernel net link device to be accessed by Kernel or normal socket application. hence the expectation of accessing DPDK ports that are bound with UIO driver in kernel space via sockets or kernel net link devices are unrealistic and incorrect.

> how to even use it now from outside the server or is it even possible with single NIC?

Please make use of sample applications such as `testpmd, l2fwd, l3fwd` to start exploring DPDK with NIC.

Please refer

1. [testpmd](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/testpmd_app_ug/)
2. [l2fwd](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/l2_forward_event.html)
3. [l3fwd](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/l3_forward.html)